# return nested JSON from SQLite with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, api, sqlite, express

I want to get nested JSON from SQLite database with NodeJS.
I did

```
app.get("/api/orders", (req, res, next) => {
    var sql = `SELECT json_object('number', o.number
                                  ,'orderType', o.orderType
                                  ,'paymentType', o.paymentType
                                  ,'isPaid', o.isPaid
                                  ,'isReady', o.isReady
                                  ,'isProgress', o.isProgress
                                  ,'isCanceled', o.isCanceled
                                  ,'isDelivered', o.isDelivered
                                  ,'createdAt', o.createdAt
                                  ,'updatedAt', o.updatedAt
                                  ,'orderItems',
                                    (SELECT json_group_array(json_object('id', ot.itemID,
                                                                         'name', ot.itemName,
                                                                         'quantity', ot.quantity))
                                    FROM orderItems AS ot WHERE ot.orderID = o.number)) AS 'order'
                FROM orders AS o`;

    db.all(sql, [], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({"error" : err.message});
            return;
        }
        res.send(result)
    });
});
```

but I get this

```
[
    {
        "order": "{\"number\":1,\"orderType\":\"Take out\",\"paymentType\":\"At counter\",\"isPaid\":0,\"isReady\":0,\"isProgress\":0,\"isCanceled\":1,\"isDelivered\":0,\"createdAt\":\"10/25/2021 15:34:48\",\"updatedAt\":\"10/25/2021 17:19:2\",\"orderItems\":[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Chicken Wings\",\"quantity\":1},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Saltado Shaken Fries\",\"quantity\":1},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Steam rice\",\"quantity\":1}]}"
    },
    {
        "order": "{\"number\":2,\"orderType\":\"Dine in\",\"paymentType\":\"Pay here\",\"isPaid\":1,\"isReady\":0,\"isProgress\":1,\"isCanceled\":0,\"isDelivered\":0,\"createdAt\":\"10/25/2021 15:35:59\",\"updatedAt\":\"10/25/2021 15:35:59\",\"orderItems\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Fam's Salad\",\"quantity\":2},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Chicken Wings\",\"quantity\":2},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Vietnamese Coffee\",\"quantity\":1}]}"
    },
    {
        "order": "{\"number\":3,\"orderType\":\"Dine in\",\"paymentType\":\"At counter\",\"isPaid\":0,\"isReady\":0,\"isProgress\":1,\"isCanceled\":0,\"isDelivered\":0,\"createdAt\":\"10/25/2021 15:44:48\",\"updatedAt\":\"10/25/2021 15:44:48\",\"orderItems\":[{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Vietnamese Coffee\",\"quantity\":1},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"Soft Drink: Coke\",\"quantity\":1}]}"
    }
]
```

It returns weird format keys like `\"number\"`, `\"orderType\"`
Is there any way that I can get a nicer JSON in this case?

Thank you